# Retrofit2: Adding access token in query parameters with interceptor

Tags: android, access-token, interceptor, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to add query parameter (access token) to every request with this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android)

The problem are the interceptors, which count will accrue in every request created by ServiceGenerator:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
```

Also cause httpClient is static, all the interceptors will be executed in requests where it doesn't needed.

Should i create own OkHttpClients for normal request and own for token request? and should i initialize interceptor and authenticator only once and then use ServiceGenerator? or is there any better approach?

Comment: You can create few clients or add headers as Header files in retrofit request

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not a good idea to add **access token** as query parameter.

Better way will be to add it to a custom header like this:

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(setCache(context))
                .certificatePinner(certificatePinnerBuilder.build())
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();

                        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                                .header("AUTH_TOKEN", token)
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();

                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
                .addInterceptor(logger)
                .build();
```

However, you can follow this link:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-add-query-parameters-to-every-request